# How do I handle time zones/offsets when displaying "posts" from various users?

Tags: php, javascript, time

It seems relativley easy.  Take javascript time (i.e. client side), compare it to your php time (server side), and you have the offset.  Save all the times in server time into your mysql table and then when displaying them, add/subtract the offset depending up on the user.  I'm guessing this is under 10 lines of code.  I don't determine the timezone as only the offset is needed.

The reason I ask is b.c. [this site](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2007/06/08/auto-detect-a-time-zone-with-javascript/) seems to make it seem a lot more involved.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I'm suggesting that you calculate the offset each time I user logs in.  This way if his client updates with Daylight Savings it does not effect anything.  Where does Javascript Date pull the time from, the OS right?  So if the OS has the wrong time likely the user does not care about "time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Slapdash Answer:** Nah, what makes his example more complicated is he is trying to find the **timezone**, you don't (from the sound of it) care about that, you just need to adjust the client time to the server's time.

And the way you suggested it is how I do it for a similar problem, and it works just fine.

**Deeper Answer:** You *could* save the client's timezone, and come up with the delta on the fly, but, unless you have several servers across different timezones, or are moving servers around in timezones, or are concerned about daylight savings (which is not observed internationally), then, your solution should be fine.

The simple offset works in just that, simple cases. The more thorough of taking the timezone and only saving the server time and then producing the offset later will scale better.

**Update** A smart person pointed out that the client time is not always accurate, and indeed it is not. An ideal solution would be to just ask the user what timezone they are in.

Comment: If you application already stores user preferences, then it's easier to add a Time Zone preference and save only the server time. You can't always be sure a user's client-side time is accurate.

Comment: Absolutely, and I recommend the more robust of saving the timezone, BUT, the example he gave for automatically finding the client's timezone USES the client's time, so he would have that problem either way. Yes, ideally, he could just *ask* the user what timezone they are in...

Comment: The trade off is - a complexity increase of about 100x to account for a user not keeping his OS's time up to date. Would be ideal if I had the time or money to pay someone else to do it